# Running tensorflow model on android 8

Tags: python

Please can someone help me to solve these errors :

1-

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to
>   create a directory:    [[Node: save/SaveV2 = SaveV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/SaveV2/tensor_names, save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices, Variable,
>   Variable/Adam, Variable/Adam_1, Variable_1, Variable_1/Adam,
>   Variable_1/Adam_1, Variable_10, Variable_10/Adam, Variable_10/Adam_1,
>   Variable_11, Variable_11/Adam, Variable_11/Adam_1, Variable_2,
>   Variable_2/Adam, Variable_2/Adam_1, Variable_3, Variable_3/Adam,
>   Variable_3/Adam_1, Variable_4, Variable_4/Adam, Variable_4/Adam_1,
>   Variable_5, Variable_5/Adam, Variable_5/Adam_1, Variable_6,
>   Variable_6/Adam, Variable_6/Adam_1, Variable_7, Variable_7/Adam,
>   Variable_7/Adam_1, Variable_8, Variable_8/Adam, Variable_8/Adam_1,
>   Variable_9, Variable_9/Adam, Variable_9/Adam_1, beta1_power,
>   beta2_power)]]

2-

> ValueError: Parent directory of tfdroid.ckpt doesn't exist, can't
>   save.

Here is the function that causes the two errors :

```
def tester(x) :
    # Get our data
    getTrainTest(n_classes)
    # Construct model
    pred = alex_net(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        #save the graph
        tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def,'.','tfdroid.pbtxt')
        # Training our network
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            while i < len(Xtrain):
                start = i
                end = i + batch_size
                # epoch_x, epoch_y = Dtrain.train.next_batch(batch_size)

            epoch_x = np.array(Xtrain[start:end])
            epoch_y = np.array(Ytrain[start:end])
            print(epoch_x.shape)

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y,keep_prob:1. })
            epoch_loss += c
            i = i + batch_size

        print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss :', epoch_loss)

    saver.save(sess, 'tfdroid.ckpt')
```

Comment: Please format your question and code properly

Comment: Thank you for your response , is it clear now?